# Facebook app cannot play videos

Tags: facebook

No videos work on my Facebook App. It says:

> Cannot play video. Sorry but an unknown error occured while trying to play this video

Comment: Please add more information like your phone model number, Android OS version and how you are connected to the internet (3G / WiFi)?

Comment: Try reinstalling the facebook app and check whether it works..